# Haskell : Memory in use inside of a function doesn't appear to be deallocated

Tags: haskell, memory, optimization

I'm attempting to write a raytracer in Haskell, however I'm running into issues where increasing the samples per pixel massively increases memory usage beyond what I would expect - having written raytracers in C before.

Here is an image showing heap profiling
I expect that the issue has something to do with the results of the `casted` function, but I'm not sure how to resolve it
[image: Here is an image showing heap profiling]

I have attempted to make the garbage collectors life easier by fully processing a pixel at once, before it is returned from `raycast` - so that all memory required to do that should be garbage collected once the pixel is processed, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

I apologize if this question is too general.

```
--data Vector4 a = Vector4 a a a a
data Vector3 a = Vector3 a a a
data World = World [Sphere] [Plane] [Material]
-- (Material emitColor refColor specular)
-- specular of 0 is pure diffuse 1 is mirror
data Material = Material (Vector3 Float) (Vector3 Float) Float
-- (Camera position x y z)
data Camera = Camera (Vector3 Float) (Vector3 Float) (Vector3 Float) (Vector3 Float)
-- (Sphere position radius materialIndex
data Sphere = Sphere (Vector3 Float) Float Int
-- (Plane normal distance materialIndex)
data Plane = Plane (Vector3 Float) Float Int

--I'm sure there is a better way of representing this, but I'm only using it once
--So I'm not too worried
infinity :: Float
infinity =
read "Infinity"

--numBounces simply caps the number of bounces before a ray is considered "dead"
numBounces :: Int
numBounces = 8

--samples per pixel
spp :: Int
spp = 16

skyMat :: Material
skyMat = Material (Vector3 0.3 0.4 0.5) (Vector3 0.0 0.0 0.0) 0.0

planeMat :: Material
planeMat = Material (Vector3 0.0 0.0 0.0) (Vector3 0.5 0.5 0.5) 0.0

sphereMat :: Material
sphereMat = Material (Vector3 0.3 0.5 0.7) (Vector3 0.7 0.5 0.3) 1.0

materials :: [Material]
materials = [skyMat, planeMat, sphereMat]

main :: IO ()
main = do
let imageWidth = 800
let imageHeight = 600
let imageSize = imageWidth * imageHeight

let cameraPos = Vector3 0.0 10.0 1.0
let camera = getCamera cameraPos (normalize cameraPos)
let plane = Plane (Vector3 0.0 0.0 1.0) 0.0 1
let sphere = Sphere (Vector3 0.0 0.0 0.0) 1.0 2
{-
let sphere2 = Sphere (Vector3 (-2.0) 0.0 1.0) 1.0 1
let sphere3 = Sphere (Vector3 2.0 0.0 2.0) 1.0 1
-}
let world = World [sphere] [plane]
            materials

putStr "\nCastin'!\n"
saveBMP (concat $ rayCast imageSize camera world 0 imageWidth imageHeight) imageWidth imageHeight
putStr "Done!\n"

fstList2 :: [(a, b)] -> [a]
fstList2 ((x, _):xs) =
x : fstList2 xs
fstList2 [] = []

rayCast :: Int -> Camera -> World -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [[Word.Word8]]
rayCast num cam world index imageWidth imageHeight
| num > 0 = (do
                -- index = x + width * y
                -- index % width = x
                -- index = x + width * y
                -- -(width * y) = x - index
                -- width * y = index - x
                -- y = (index - x) / width

                let gen = pureMT $ fromIntegral index
                let x = index `mod` imageWidth
                let y = (index - x) `div` imageWidth
                let filmX = (-1.0) + 2.0 * ((fromIntegral x) / (fromIntegral imageWidth))
                let filmY = (-1.0) + 2.0 * ((fromIntegral y) / (fromIntegral imageHeight))

                let (Camera cPos cX cY cZ) = cam
                let filmW = 1.0
                let filmH = filmW * ((fromIntegral imageHeight) / (fromIntegral imageWidth))
                let filmDist = 1.0
                let filmCenter = cPos `v3Sub` (cZ `v3Scale` filmDist)
                let filmPoint = (filmCenter `v3Add` (cX `v3Scale` (filmX * 0.5 * filmW))) `v3Add` (cY `v3Scale` (filmY * 0.5 * filmH))

                let rayOrigin = cPos
                let rayDir = normalize (filmPoint `v3Sub` cPos)
                -- from my understanding casted should simply be a [Vector3 Float] that is 16 elements long
                -- this should then be garbage collected as soon as we call rayCast again below
                -- yet I suspect it is persisting - lazy evaluation?
                let casted = castSamples gen spp rayOrigin rayDir world 0
                let contribution = 1.0 / (fromIntegral spp)
                (vecToWord8 (foldr (avgVec contribution) (Vector3 0.0 0.0 0.0) casted)) : rayCast (num - 1) cam world (index + 1) imageWidth imageHeight)
| otherwise = []

avgVec :: Float -> Vector3 Float -> Vector3 Float -> Vector3 Float
avgVec contribution a b =
(a `v3Scale` contribution) `v3Add` b

castSamples :: PureMT -> Int -> Vector3 Float -> Vector3 Float -> World -> Int -> [Vector3 Float]
castSamples generator samples rOrigin rDir world timesBounced
| samples /= 0 = (let tupleList = castWorld generator rOrigin rDir world timesBounced
                    --castWorld returns a [(Int, PureMT)], PureMT being the random number generator
                    --that is in use
                        casted = fstList2 tupleList
                        (_, newGen) = last tupleList
                        initPair = ((Vector3 0.0 0.0 0.0), (Vector3 1.0 1.0 1.0)) 
                        result = fst $! foldr attenuate initPair (reverse (casted)) in
                    result : castSamples newGen (samples - 1) rOrigin rDir world timesBounced)
| otherwise = []

attenuate :: Int ->
            (Vector3 Float, Vector3 Float) ->
            (Vector3 Float, Vector3 Float)
attenuate matIndex (accumulatedColor, attenuation)
| matIndex == 0 = (let (Material emitColor _ _) = materials !! 0 in
                    (accumulatedColor `v3Add` (v3Hadamard attenuation emitColor), attenuation))
| otherwise = let (Material emitColor refColor _) = materials !! matIndex
                    newAttenuation = v3Hadamard attenuation refColor in
                (accumulatedColor `v3Add` (v3Hadamard attenuation emitColor), newAttenuation)
```

Comment: What is `vecToWord8` and doesn't `rayCast` look way too lazy? (in particular, when is `index` forced?)

Comment: `castSamples` has a `(_, newGen)` pattern and a `$!`, but neither force anything. This is equivalent to `newGen = snd (...)` and `result = fst (...)` without `$!`, and both are thunks when `castSamples` returns.

Comment: One thing that would help a lot is to use vectors (especially the `Storable` kind) instead of lists.

Comment: If you'd like to squeeze all the performance take a look at this implementation: https://github.com/mkawalec/raytracer as well as the corresponding talk: https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/12387-raytracing-with-haskell

Comment: @Li-yaoXia vecToWord8 just converts a spatial vector to an array of 8 bit ints. How would I use $! so that it forces?

Comment: I think the main problem is using the wrong data structures. There are leaks all over the place because of lists and lazy records, so the best use of your time would be to overhaul everything to use a stricter representation like vectors. If you really want to experiment with the current structure, forget about `$!`, enable `BangPatterns` and mark let-bindings that should be forced with `!`: for example, `let ... ; !result = ... in`. Also avoid applying constructors to non-variable expressions. `foo x : bar a` would be better as `let !hd_ = foo x ; !tl_ = bar a in hd_ : tl_`.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Thank you for the advice

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations? (also see the checklist here https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info) . Please include an example people can run; your formatting is fubar, for one